# What are CLD and STD for in x86 assembly language? What does DF do?

Tags: assembly, x86

well, I know that CLD clears direction flag and STD sets direction flag. 
but what's the point in setting and clearing direction flag?

Comment: Ugh, the number of bugs that bit caused.  My Turbo Pascal code was peppered with inline assembly to reset it.

Answer (score 49):

The direction flag is used to influence the direction in which string instructions offset pointer registers.  These are the same instructions that can be used [with the `REP` prefix](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html) to repeat the operation.
  (Although `lods` isn't very useful with `rep`).

The string instructions are: [`MOVS`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html) (copy mem to mem), `STOS` (store AL/AX/EAX/RAX), `SCAS` (scan string), `CMPS` (compare string), and `LODS` (load string).  There's also `ins`/`outs` for copying between memory and an IO port.  Each of these instructions is available in byte, word, dword, and qword operand sizes.

In a nutshell, when the direction flag is 0, the instructions work by incrementing the pointer to the data after every iteration (until `ECX` is zero or some other condition, depending on the flavour of the `REP` prefix), while if the flag is 1, the pointer is decremented.

For example, [`movsd`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_203.html) copies a dword from `[ds:esi]` to `[es:edi]` (or rdi in 64-bit mode), and does this:  (See the "Operation" section in the linked ISA reference manual entry extracted from Intel's PDFs)

```
dword [es:edi] = dword [ds:esi]      // 4-byte copy memory to memory
if (DF == 0)
    esi += 4;
    edi += 4;
else  // DF == 1
    esi -= 4;
    edi -= 4;
fi
```

With a REP prefix, it does this ECX times, and modern x86 CPUs have optimized "fast strings" microcode that does the copying (or `stos` storing) with 16-byte or 32-byte internal operations.  See also [this Q&A about memory bandwidth and the ERMSB feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy).  (Note that only `rep stos` and `rep movs` are optimized this way, not `repne/repe scas` or `cmps`).

Comment: Here is a [minimal runnable example with assertions](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/6a9299599e781b29abfce64e4923ab0af3ef731d/userland/arch/x86_64/stos.S).

Answer (score 12):

CLD CLears the Direction flag, data goes onwards.
STD SeTs the Direction flag, data goes backwards.

Answer (score 4):

If using Windows, then as per the STDCALL calling convention -

> Under STDCALL, the direction flag is clear on entry and must be
>   returned clear.

So if you set DF, then before an API call you must clear it.

Comment: Operating System Dependant.

Comment: This is common to most 32-bit / 64-bit calling conventions, including i386 System V and x86-64 System V.  It lets you (or the compiler) efficiently inline `rep movsd` / `rep stosd` without CLD instructions.  (On modern x86, they're often only fast going upward, with DF=0)

Answer (score 4):

CLD: clear direction flag so that string pointers 
  auto increment after each string operation

STD:
std is used to set the direction flag to a 1 so that SI and/or DI will automatically be decremented to point to the next string element when one of the string instruction executes.If the direction flag is set SI/DI will be decremented by 1 for byte strings and 2 for word strings.

This answer can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

CLD:
Clears the DF flag in the EFLAGS register. When the DF flag is set to 0, string operations increment the index registers (ESI and/or EDI).

here is a simple example:

```
section .text
global main
main:
    mov ecx, len
    mov esi, s1
    mov edi, s2

    cld       ; redundant because DF is already guaranteed to be 0 on function entry
              ; but included for illustration purposes

loop_here:
    lodsb                ; AL=[esi],  ESI+=1 (because DF=0, otherwise ESI-=1)
    add al, 02
    stosb                ; [edi]=AL,  EDI+=1 (because DF=0, otherwise EDI-=1)
    loop loop_here       ; like dec ecx / jnz but without setting flags
    ; ECX=0, EDI and ESI pointing to the end of their buffers

    mov edx, len-1       ;message length, not including the terminating 0 byte
    mov ecx,s2           ;message to write
    mov ebx,1            ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4            ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80             ;call kernel

    mov  eax,1           ;system call number (sys_exit)
    xor  ebx,ebx
    int  0x80            ;call kernel: sys_exit(0)

section .data
s1: db 'password', 0        ; source buffer
len equ $-s1

section .bss
s2: resb len                ; destination buffer
```

(assemble and link with `nasm -felf32 caesar.asm && gcc -no-pie -m32 caesar.o -o caesar`.  Or link it into a static executable with this as `_start` instead of `main` if you like.)

(this example tried to implement Caesar cipher.)

Comment: The i386 System V calling convention already guarantees DF=0 on entry to a function, which is why your program works reliably even though you use `lodsb`/`stosb` before running `cld`.   The `rep movsb` runs with ECX=0 (from `loop`), so it copies zero bytes past the end of `s1`/`s2`, and it doesn't matter what DF is set to at that point.

Comment: BTW, [`loop` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently), don't use it unless you're optimizing for code-size over speed.  Also, you probably want to wrap around the last 2 letters of the alphabet to the first 2.  So it does make sense to load and operate on a byte in a register, but only if you're going to implement a check for wrapping.  Otherwise you could modify a string in-place with `add byte [esi], 2` / `inc esi`.  Or do 4 bytes at once with `add dword [esi], 0x02020202`, if it won't carry...

Comment: thank you. i try to fix issues you mentioned in my code :)