# Input a multiple digit number from user in assembly 8086 Language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I am trying to input a three (say) digit number from the user through `INT 21H` (DOS) and save it in a resister. Normally what we do is to input a single character from the user. The corresponding code is:

```
MOV AH,1
INT 21H
```

The above code takes a single digit input from the user (from 0 to 9).the input is saved in the register AL

But what can I do if I want to input a multiple digit number from the user? (say 456)

Can anyone provide a sample code for that?

Comment: Or use line buffered input (`0Ah`).

Comment: Yes but I am looking for a sample code as I am little bit confused in using the resisters. Can you provide me that? @Daniel Kamil Kozar

Comment: but how will i store it in a resister?

Comment: read, multiply and add, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you want...

```
          Lea Di, The_Buffer      ;Define this somewhere
          CLD                     ;Incrementing direction

  Get_another_byte:

          Mov AH, 1               ;Ms.Dos code to get one char
          Int 21h                 ;Ms.Dos does that for us and puts it in AL

          Cmp AL, 0Dh             ;Did he hit the return key ?
          Je  He_is_done          ;Yes, now we can go on

          Stosb                   ;Else no put the byte in the buffer
          Jmp Get_another_byte    ;He's not done, so keep on


  He_is_done:

          Nop                     ;Blah
          Nop                     ;Blah
          Nop                     ;Blah
          Nop                     ;
          Nop                     ;
          Nop                     ;Replace this with your real stuff here
          Nop                     ;
          Nop                     ;
          Nop                     ;
```

Now, about that `CLD` instruction, be all kinds of careful, and make sure you do that.

[THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636691/whats-the-difference-between-cld-and-std-instructions-in-assembly-language) on Stack Overflow has some important advice about it, and your very problem is precisely applicable